# Why is pymongo not returning index information of the collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

If I run the getIndexes method in the shell :

```
xyz:PRIMARY> db.my_collection.count()
26672
xyz:PRIMARY> db.my_collection.getIndexes()
// Prints indexes and their info
```

However, `index_information` method in pymongo is returning a blank
dict for all collections in python shell, other operations on the
collection work fine.

```
>>> my_collection.count()
26672
>>> my_collection.index_information()
{}
```

Mongodb version : 3.0.2

Pymongo version : 2.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Python Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#python-driver-compatibility) section in MongoDB documentation, PyMongo 2.5 does not fully support MongoDB 3.0:

[image]

<sup>*Python Driver Compatibility (From MongoDB Documentation)*</sup>

So you should upgrade your PyMongo to the latest version or 2.8 at least.

Comment: Thanks. That could be the most probable reason, though the driver works well and is performant for most other operations.